# How to intercalate 2 lists in lisp and print a statement when the list lengths don't match

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

How do you intercalate two lists and check for matching list lengths and print a statement when the lengths don't match? I can make it continue when one list becomes null, but how to error it out completely from the start when lengths don't match?

```
(defun intercalate (list1 list2)
  (cond 
    ((and (eql list1 nil) (eql list2 nil)) nil)
    ((null list1) list2)
    (t (cons (first list1) (intercalate list2 (rest list1))))))
```

```
(print (intercalate '(1 3 5) '(2)))
```

**will return**

(1 2 3 5)

**but i want it to return**

"List lengths must match"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

```
(defun intercalate (list1 list2)
  (labels ((recursive (list1 list2)
             (cond ((null list1)
                    (when list2 
                      (return-from intercalate "List lengths must match")))
                   (t (cons (first list1) (recursive list2 (rest list1)))))))
    (recursive list1 list2)))
```

For instance:

```
CL-USER> (intercalate '(1 3 4) '(10 20 30))
(1 10 3 20 4 30)
CL-USER> (intercalate '(1 3 4) '(2))
"List lengths must match"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is probably how I would do it: traverse the list one more time than needed, for clarity, until speed actually becomes a problem.

The idea of the recursion, for me, is to do "two steps" at once (that is, pop from both lists).

```
(defun intercalate (list1 list2)
  (assert (= (length list1) (length list2))
          nil
          "Lists lengths must match")
  (labels ((aux (l1 l2)
             (if l1
                 (list* (car l1)
                        (car l2)
                        (aux (cdr l1) (cdr l2)))
                 nil)))
    (aux list1 list2)))
```

This can of course be made tail-recursive, to (try to) avoid recursion depth problems (if the compiler optimizes it):

```
(defun intercalate-tail-recursive (list1 list2)
  (assert (= (length list1) (length list2))
          nil
          "Lists lengths must match")
  (labels ((aux (l1 l2 acc)
             (if l1
                 (aux (cdr l1)
                      (cdr l2)
                      (list* (car l1) (car l2) acc))
                 (nreverse acc))))
    (aux list1 list2 nil)))
```

You can also do it easily with the `loop` macro:

```
(defun intercalate-loop (list1 list2)
  (loop :initially (assert (= (length list1) (length list2))
                           nil
                           "Lists lengths must match")
        :for x :in list1
        :for y :in list2
        :collect x
        :collect y))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an optional parameter for an accumulator to create a tail-recursive `intercalate` function which returns the string `"List lengths must match"` on a length mismatch between arguments. Using this optional parameter avoids the necessity of a recursive inner function.

```
(defun intercalate (list1 list2 &optional (acc nil))
  (cond 
    ((and (null list1) (null list2))
     (reverse acc))
    ((or (null list1) (null list2))
     "List lengths must match")
    (t (intercalate (cdr list1) (cdr list2)
                    (cons (car list2) 
                          (cons (car list1) acc))))))
```